# Integrate FirebaseUI to app/build.gradle cause crash at runtime

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, build.gradle, firebaseui

Adding

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
```

into `dependencies` of the *app/build.grandle* File, cause an Error every Time I call `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()`. Before I added the new gradle Dependency, every `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` Call works fine and also I was able to load Data from FirebaseDatabase. 
Iam doing this Tutorial: [FirebaseUI for Android — Auth](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md). What did I wrong?

**Update 1:** Put the calls into an Try/Catch Block doesnt work. The Debbuger does not step into the catch Part.

**UPDATE 2:** 
*What is the Error?* Answer: I dont get an Error. The Logcat Box do not print any Error Message. Also I cant figgure out the error via debugging, becaus the Catch-Block dont get reached.

My app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    //FirebaseUI
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1') // Required only if Facebook login support is required
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, change this lines of code:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
```

with

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'
```

Comment: Your answer was almost completely correct. Only for firebase-ui-auth I had to use the version number 2.3.0. Because in Version 1.2.0 a Twitter Packet was needet, but I dont want to integrate Twitter yet.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to using right version number for firebase-ui-auth at gradle. You can read the official document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 0):

Just check [the compatibility](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries):

```
FirebaseUI Version  Firebase/Play Services Version
2.3.0               11.0.4
```

If you want to use the `firebase-ui 2.3.0` you have to use `firebase 11.0.4`.

Use:

```
//Firebase
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
//FirebaseUI
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
```